# Activities to do with children in and near Jerusalem in the summer, especially to avoid the heat?

Tags: children, israel, summer, jerusalem

What is there to do in Jerusalem in the summer months with 4 year old and 10 year old boys. I am looking for activities to avoid the heat and sun that is present much of the day.  I will be evaluating these activities in terms of things that will keep them amused and make for good memories. Seeking ideas in addition to the usual tourist attractions, since most of the usual attractions are adult oriented.

The two children do not have to stay together, but they can. They will be accompanied by several adults.

For both, hands on experiences will probably work best.  Outdoor, physical activities might be good, but we also need something to do in the hot mid-day hours.  Interacting with other kids might be nice, but language might be a barrier.

So far people have suggested the tank museum in Latrun and [a new water park](http://rjstreets.com/2013/08/13/jerusalems-new-water-park/).  Both should be good in the heat, due to shade and water.  The zoo, on the other hand, is out in the open and really hot in the summer months.

Any other ideas or suggestions will be appreciated.

P.S. Two places I found on a recent trip: (1) a large swimming pool (heated, and part is covered, with some lawn and a snack bar) on Emek Refaim Street in Jerusalem and (2) an indoor playground (air conditioned) at the old train station in Jerusalem. Also, there are many playgrounds in the residential neighborhoods.

Comment: The same question was allowed for Paris.  R/open voted.

Comment: If this question is not appropriate for this forum (and I did model the question after the Paris one), where might I go to get the question answered?

Comment: You might want to add information on what the children like to do. Is there any theme you might want to explore, for example?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC It's appropriate to the site if there's more detail like ages, hobbies, interest in history, etc etc.  I have an answer ready when it gets reopened.

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC, edit the question, add the content, and then click 'reopen'

Comment: @Gayot Fow  I've editied the question. But where is 'reopen'?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC, to the right of the edit button

Comment: @Gayot My screen shows "share edit delete flag" followed by "edited 12 hours ago". What am I missing?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC, I'll raise it with the moderators...

Comment: Just by editing, it enters the reopen queue for other members to review.

Comment: @MarkMayo  I edited the question but it is still closed.  There was no reopen button that I noticed. What should I do now?

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC Nothing, it's open now!

Answer (score 7):

There are many options for a family visit to Jerusalem in the summer heat. After all most families in Israel have at least two children.

- The [Israel Museum](http://www.imj.org.il/en/) is air-conditioned and has plenty of Family Activities listed on their website, including a mini-theater
- Explore the [Western Wall Tunnels](http://english.thekotel.org/), which feature 500 meters of cool space underneath the Western Wall.
- Visit the [Siloam/Hezekiah's tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siloam_tunnel)
- Learn about the history of Jerusalem in [Time Elevator Jerusalem](http://www.time-elevator-jerusalem.co.il/en/time-elevator.asp), where the kids can enjoy an interactive movie in a moving chair.
- As you've mentioned in your question, the First Jerusalem Train Station features an air-conditioned playground

Answer (score 3):

You can add the list the [Jerusalem Science Museum](https://www.mada.org.il/en) which is kiddie-friendly and encourages hands-on touching of almost all displays.